# How do I find LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress inside the loaded kernel32.dll?

Tags: winapi, memory, assembly, kernel32

I am trying to make a small win32 "Hello, world!" application in pure assembly.
Now after looking around on how to even locate the `kernel32.dll`, I, after some time, found this: http://skypher.com/wiki/index.php/Hacking/Shellcode/kernel32. This technique returns a pointer to where `kernel32.dll` is located in memory.

Now on a different website where a similar technique was presented, they wrote

> Now all you need to do is locate the "LoadLibrary" and "GetProcAddress" functions in there and you're good to go!

Of course, this is true. I could easily write any win32 application if I only had the exact jump location of these two functions.

Does anyone know how to locate the two (or technically, only "GetProcAddress" would do) in that DLL? Or are there any cheap alternatives (besides using a higher-level language)?

Thanks in advance,

-Kierrow

Comment: Um, why not just import it like a normal program? That way you won't get flagged as malware. Oh wait, the fact that you're looking at shellcode means that you are already writing malware...

Comment: @RaymondChen True, but how do I do this? - This might sound weird, but I'm not using a compiler/assembler...

Comment: You said you're writing it in assembly. So why not use an assembler? Link to the import library.

Comment: @RaymondChen This is something for my advanced computer sciences class. I don't want to get into detail about the "why", but I have studied and tried to understand machine code instructions and the most basic low-level programming for the past weeks. The main problem I am at right now is this... I have tried to do what some already recommended me to do: Look into a very simple, compiled C/C++ program, but I was not able to find out what I asked about in this question, hence me asking.

Comment: Read up on the Portable Executable (PE) file format.

Comment: @RaymondChen oh I did. I read Microsoft's PE specifications as well as some other random sources I found on the web. Now I might just did not catch this in there, but I still don't know how to manage to get to these basic methods.

Comment: Write a program and use the linker. Then study the linker output. I'm not going to teach you in a comment. Especially since I still think you're trying to write malware.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks, I'll try that again with more care. Just wanted to clear this up, this is by no means a malicious programming project. It's actually a compiler project for a programming language my friend and I designed, which is at the same time a school project, like I said. I will try to analyze more compiled source code, but if you have any resources that could point me to, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you found how to retrieve a pointer to kernel32.dll, you could just traverse the Export Table of kernel32 and look for "GetProcAddress". Once you get the pointer to the function, just invoke it. As Raymond Chen mentioned, to do this, just have a look at the [Portable Executable Format specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx).

Comment: FYI, GetProcAddress doesn't have a Unicode version. All imports and exports are treated as just byte strings. You can even use control codes and OS won't care a bit :)

Comment: @Igor: Of Course!! Thanks - IAT and EAT document symbol names only using ascii.

Comment: No I mean stuff like CR, LF, Ctrl-C (\x03) and so on.

Comment: @Igor: sounds new to me, could you please provide more details (URL)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take any DLL, patch an export name to be "0D 00", then use `GetProcAddress(hdll, "\x0D")`.

Comment: @Igor: is this trick often used? Can you point to sample images?

Comment: Don't think I've ever seen it used for actual linking, but garbage in export names does happen in malware, to mess with disassemblers/debuggers.

Comment: @Igor: what about Import names & garbage names? ...thanks to answer my questions :-)